# Translate Yii messages service

Tags: php, yii, translate

Messages (strings) that are used in my web application are automatically exported by Yii to .php files having content such as the following:

`return array (
  'Company' => '',
  'Name' => '',
  'Description' => '',
);`

Do you know of any service that automatically imports such messages generated by the Yii framework in order to have them translated? I am primarily interested in not having to convert to other file formats such as .po or .xml. For instance, launchpad would have been a solution to my problem if I didn't have to convert to .po.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.
`

Comment: What do you mean with `service that automatically imports such messages generated by the Yii framework in order to have them translated?`?

Comment: A service such as this one http://goo.gl/abHd where I would be able to upload .php files that contain Yii generated messages. I know I am asking a lot but I am asking just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gettext/) to utilize the popular [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) extension, then in your code, whenever you want to mark your string for translation, you can just wrap it with a special function call (after configuring it in Yii config of course):

```
return array ( 'company' => _('Company'),
    'name' => _('Name'),
    'description' => _('Description'),
);
```

then you can use the [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Template) script to extract the template file (.POT file) that will contain the actual translation of the strings:

> xgettext -j -o index.pot index.php

Then extract PO file using [msginit](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Creating)

All you have to do after that is to translate the content in the index.po file and so on...

Comment: Thanks but I have been looking for a service that would consume .php files.

Comment: This will consume your `.php` files as well.